# Friends not get invited to the created event in facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, events

I am creating an app which creates an event in facebook. I have successfully created the event in the facebook through my app, but i am not able to invite friends in it. This is what i have done.

To create the event i used the following code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Birthday Party",@"name",
                                   @"Hotel Taj",@"location",
                                   @"2013-02-02T20:00:00+0530",@"start_time",
                                   @"2013-04-02T20:00:00+0530",@"end_time", nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/events"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
```

After this I am getting the event id as response and I used the following code for inviting friends to that event.

```
NSString *graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/invited?users=%@",event,[@[@"friend1",@"friend2"] componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andDelegate:self];
```

After this I am getting a response as follows.

str = {"data":[{"name":"Testtesttest Testtest","id":"100003064304910","rsvp_status":"attending"}],"paging":{"next":"https://graph.facebook.com/191592177650963/invited?users\u00255B0\u00255D=friend1&users\u00255B1\u00255D=friend2&format=json&access_token=AAADicrEWZCQsBALS5ESFGlzrmQIFgY8nqAibPDOl6830qrPW4zZANeaMVFGslefLQfGLvZCSKrNt61vcKYkeZA2ubCRZADJhwStZCUfEXdPgZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100003064304910"}}

The friends are not get invited.

But while I tested in Graph API Explorer it returns "true" and the friends get invited. 
Please help me to fix my problem.

Comment: Could you try something?  Can you put in a 20 second delay in between sending the request to created the event and the request for the invites?  I'm thinking it's a timing issue between creation of the event id and being able to use that ID in subsequent calls.

Comment: Yes, I put 25 sec delay, but my problem not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the event, from the response you receive, you just need to send the params to the event with the event id, and the users we have selected (ie,the uids) receive the invite to the event you have created.

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoadRawResponse:(NSData *)data
{


NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
eventAddress = [results objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *formattedAddress = [results objectForKey:@"id"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                formattedAddress,@"eid",
                                @"events.invite",@"method",
                            @"uid1,uid2",@"uids",
                                nil];
[facebook requestWithParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```